# Why does a force parallel to the axis of rotation do not produce torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

One explanation can be that Torque is a cross-product (r x F). I want to know what is its physical interpretation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: Forces parallel to the axis of rotation can cause a torque, the r in the equation is the vector from the CM to where the force is being applied. You need to elaborate on your thinking.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take a particular example of a disk rotating around an axis through its centre:

[image: Disk]

If the component of the torque parallel to the axis is $T_a$ then the disk will start to rotate according to the angular version of Newton's second law:

$$ T_a = I\dot{\omega} \tag{1} $$

where $\dot{\omega}$ is the angular acceleration and $I$ is the moment of inertia. The obvious way to make this rotate is to apply a tangential force:

[image: Tangential force]

In this case the magnitude of the torque is just $T=rF$ and the direction of the torque vector is parallel to the axis so $T_a = T = rF$ and equation (1) tells us that the disk will start rotating.

Now suppose we change the direction of the force so it points directly towards the axis:

[image: Radial force]

Obviously this isn't going to make the disk rotate, and equally obviously it's because the force and radial vectors are in a line so $T = \mathbf r \times \mathbf F = 0$ i.e. the torque is zero. That means $T_a$ is zero and equation (1) tells us the disk won't rotate.

The case you ask about is this one:

[image: Upwards force]

In this case the torque is non-zero, but the torque vector $\mathbf T = \mathbf r \times \mathbf F$ points out of the screen towards us i.e. the torque vector is at 90º to the axis. That means the component of the torque parallel to the axis, $T_a$, is zero and that's why the disk won't rotate.